# Caml Query on calendar to get the next x events (including recurring)

Tags: 2013, calendar, caml, recurring-events

So far I'm able to get the next x events (without recurring events). Code:

```
    private SPListItemCollection GetNextEvents(SPList eventCalendar)
    {
        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        string currentDateTimeString = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(currentDateTime);
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.RowLimit = 3;
        query.ExpandRecurrence = true;            
        query.Query = "<Where>" +                    
                          "<And>" +
                            "<Geq>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />" +
                                "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='True'>" +
                                    currentDateTimeString +
                                "</Value>" +
                            "</Geq>" +
                            "<Geq>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
                                "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='True'>" +
                                    currentDateTimeString +
                                "</Value>" +
                            "</Geq>" +
                          "</And>" +
                        "</Where>" +
                        "<OrderBy>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
                        "</OrderBy>";            

        SPListItemCollection itemColl = eventCalendar.GetItems(query);

        return itemColl;
    }
```

Setting `query.ExpandRecurrence = true` didn't help. I also tried the solution suggested [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67486/caml-query-to-get-the-next-event-from-calendar). Somehow I can't get it working with recurring events. For the following example I'd like to get the 2nd and 3rd "OK Repeating Event" and the "OK1" event since it starts earlier than "OK2"
[image: CalendarImage]

Answer (score 1):

Apart from setting `ExpandRecurrence` property of `SPQuery` to `true`, you also need to specify the `DateRangesOverlap` in the query to get the recurrence events. Example:

```
SPList list = web.Lists["Company Calendar"];                                       
SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
oQuery.ExpandRecurrence = true;                     
oQuery.Query = "<Where><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
"<FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />" +
"<Value Type='DateTime'><Now /></Value>" +
"</DateRangesOverlap></Where>";                     
oQuery.CalendarDate = DateTime.Now;                    
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(oQuery);                    
foreach(SPListItem item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}, StartDate: {1}", item.Title, item["EventDate"]);
}
```

See [Recurring Calendar Events](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2015/05/sharepoint-recurring-calendar-events.html) for more information.

Comment: Problem is that `DateRangedOverlap` also returns events that started in the past what I do not want (for example the NOK1 event from the picture). Is there a way to combine `DateRangesOverlap` with the query from above which returns items that start and end in the future?

Comment: You can use And/Or operators to create such query.

Comment: It seems I don't see the woods for the trees. From my understanding the And-Operator doesn't make sense because the recurring events come from the `DateRangesOverlap` part and won't get returned with the query from my original post. The Or-Operator wouldn't work because the `DateRangesOverlap` query returns items that begun in the past and end today, which I don't want to get returned.

Comment: Using `Now` in `DateRangesOverlap` query will give you events from today and the events which are within 2 years in future.

Comment: I am using `Now` as in your example but it still returns items that started in the past and end today (only the day seems to matter for the `EndDate`, not the time. Using `IncludeTimeValue='True'` for the `Value` element doesn't help)