# Calendar List - CAML Query Next Two Events

Tags: 2010, caml-query, calendar, recurring-events, ssom

I need to create a CAML query to obtain the following two events from a SharePoint 2010 calendar:

To consider:

- There may be recurring events
- And exceptions to events

The purpose is to show in a webpart the following two events, ie, greater than or equal to today.

Thanks!

Comment: like https://gordonduthie.net/2014/02/11/recurring-non-recurring-calendar-events-caml-in-sharepoint-2013/?

Comment: Try this... http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67486/caml-query-to-get-the-next-event-from-calendar?rq=1

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you dealing with?

Comment: SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite difficult to make such queries. The documentation is somewhat ambiguous and contradictory in some cases. Finally this query gave me good results. I leave it here in case anyone else is interested.

```
SPQuery consulta = new SPQuery();

consulta.ViewFields = "";
consulta.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>";
consulta.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='EventDate'/>";
consulta.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='EndDate'/>";
consulta.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='fRecurrence'/>";
consulta.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceData'/>";
consulta.ViewFields += "<FieldRef Name='fAllDayEvent'/>";

consulta.ExpandRecurrence = true;
// consulta.CalendarDate = DateTime.Now;

consulta.Query = "<Where><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'><Now/></Value></DateRangesOverlap></Where>";
consulta.Query += "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /></OrderBy>";

consulta.RowLimit = 2;
```

Source of inspiration:

http://sharepointchan.blogspot.com.ar/2011/10/situation-i-want-to-get-all-calendar.html

http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/04/26/use-spservices-to-get-recurring-events-as-distinct-items-aspx/

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to avoid the CAML and use calendar views. According to this [blog post](http://www.sharepointpanda.com/2011/04/sharepoint-2010-calendar-list-views-and-recurring-events-an-adaptation-of-using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/), you can create a view that shows recurring events and displays them in chronological order.  Then at the end of the view definition, you can limit the view to show the next 2 items.

To create the view, go to the calendar and follow these steps:

1. Ribbon -> Calendar -> Create View
2. Select "Standard View, With expanded Recurring Events"
3. Name the View and arrange the Columns - I put Start Time near the front.
4. At the bottom under Item Limit, select 2

The View will display like so:

[image]

This view can be overlaid onto another calendar or pulled into another site using a Web Part.  This solution is simpler and out of the box and is easier to maintain than a coded solution involving CAML and CSOM.

Comment: It is a very good choice. In my case a bit complicated because I develop all in C #. That means that the views also have to create in C # for each of the sites. But I like the idea of using standard functionality. Thank you!

Comment: For people who visit this question in the future - this solution works Out Of the Box (OOB) whereas the accepted answer by the OP involves a developer, installation and runs on the farm.